# What did I see in Key West and the Pacific Northwest?

Tags: riddle

I saw one in Key West, and then I saw one in the Pacific Northwest. It has seven letters in its name, and uses each of the 5 standard vowels exactly once.

What did I see?

Comment: I found the "all five vowels in 7 letters" clue a total giveaway and the other ones too vague to be useful, though "Pacific Northwest" gave confirmation when I Googled it with the answer. I think this riddle would be better if the clues were more "balanced" in helpfulness so that one would need to put them together.

Comment: We have google though.  Google the relevant terms and the answer to your question will be on the first page, if not the first link.

Comment: Also people here are pros

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it a

> Sequoia?

Only word I know that fits the description.

Explanation:

> A [Sequoia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequoia_%28genus%29) is a type of tree that grows in the Pacific Northwest.  It is also the name of a [Toyota SUV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toyota_Sequoia).  Whether this vehicle is particularly popular in Key West, I do not know.

Comment: I only heard of this city just now, so I guess you saw a Toyota ____?

Comment: I'm confused, what's the connection between Key West and Toyota?

Comment: @wildBillMunson I haven't and neither have most people here. Nor did Google turn up anything. So, it's too obscure as a clue.

Comment: @wildBill yes it's too obscure. also McMagister, please provide a full explanation

Answer (score 3):

You saw "The AIOU".

The AIOU is a research facility/university in pakistan.  Upon your travels you saw some of their handiwork in the form of a peer reviewed paper.